How to investigate the overriding of a keymap?
In the magit commit message buffer, I once was able to get the previous commit message using M-p in evil edit mode. Exactly how it's expected. Now I'm required to enter into evil insert mode hitting i mode before doing that.
Looking at the keybinding of M-p with C-h k I see it's bound to evil-mc-make-and-goto-prev-cursor yet I'm unable to make any relation looking at my init.el.
Furthermore I get this echo when entering the commit message:
Type , c to finish, , k to cancel, and <visual-state> g k  and <visual-state> g j to recover older messages

Remove the multiple-cursors layer
